# Naming functions based on popularity

Tags: php, function, naming

You need two functions:
1. Retrieves plain text from a DB.
2. Based on 1, retrieves rich text - with new lines, font styles etc.

You expect function 2 to be much more used than function 1.

Would you name 1 text() and 2 - rich_text() or would you use the simpler text() for the name of 2, since it's expected to be more popular and use something like plain_text() for 1?

The more general question would be - do you consider function's expected "popularity" when naming it?

Comment: I'm going to call my favorite function `happy_happy_joy_joy()` so everyone else will love it and use it without giving half a crap what it does!

Comment: @Thilo, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm just saying, all things equal, for me a function named "rich_text" would be less popular. But that was not really a serious comment ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock, I'm not sure I get your point. Do you mean to point out that the names I'm suggesting in my question are irrelevant to what the functions they describe do?

Comment: @Emanuil: I mean there's no reason to choose names based on popularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't consider a function's popularity. It's best to have descriptive names for both functions (e.g. one is `plain_text()` and one is `rich_text()`).

I think that it's best to use relatively specific names for all functions, since using more general names 1.) doesn't give the user too much of an idea of what the function does by reading the name and 2.) can lead to confusion.

Of course, how you name your functions is your choice: I just recommend that you give them somewhat descriptive names and that you name them (and order the arguments) consistently.

I hate nothing more than programming with an API where every function name is short and cryptic (PHP's string functions are that way, even though I'm used to it now -- `strstr` and `strtok` are hardly intuitive names for what they do).

Answer (score 2):

It's worth thinking about popularity, sometimes, if the code is going to be very widely used.  Common words in natural languages tend to be short.

Unless you think you're writing the next UNIX, however, you're probably better off to make the names descriptive and not worry about length.

I'd go for `getPlainText()` and `getRichText()`.

Comment: But even Ken Thompson regrets leaving the 'e' out of `creat()`, so if you **are** writing the next UNIX, please take natural languages into account.

Comment: Yeah, but I've been dealing with code that runs to names like getThingAndResturnAsJsonForDojoData.  Descriptive as hell, but hard to work with.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, I always name my functions loosely based on what they do. If I was in your shoes, I would name function one `retrieve_plain_text()` and function two `retrieve_rich_text()`. I can now glance at either function name and immediately have a basic understanding of what the function is supposed to do: Retrieve (get from something, in this case the database) plain/rich (the type) text.